# How to get ' Set-Cookie ' header value by Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, rest, mobile

I am developing a cordova application. After login i need session id for all server call. For that i need to get session id from Set-Cookie header. In angular $http service didn't show Set-Cookie in response header. How i got the Set-Cookie?

```
$http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:3000/contacts",
            data: JSON.stringify({'key':'value'})
        }).success(function(res,status, header, config){

            console.log(config, header);

        }).error(function(err){
            alert('Unautherized '+JSON.stringify(err));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an $http interceptor that reads the value from the cookie and sends it in every request. Cookie can be read with [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) service. Example:

```
$cookie.get('session');
```

To use $cookies service don't forget to add [ngCookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies) module as a dependency first.